# Loading data from HDFS to HBASE

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

I'm using Apache hadoop 1.1.1 and Apache hbase 0.94.3.I wanted to load data from HDFS to HBASE.
I wrote pig script to serve the purpose. First i created hbase table in habse and next wrote pig script to load the data from HDFS to HBASE. But it is not loading the data into hbase table. Dont know where it's going worng.
Below is the command used to craete hbase table :

create table 'mydata','mycf'

Below is the pig script to load data from hdfs to hbase:

```
    A = LOAD '/user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (c1:int, c2:chararray,c3:chararray,c4:int,c5:chararray);   
    STORE A INTO 'hbase://mydata'
    USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
          'mycf:c1,mycf:c2,mycf:c3,mycf:c4,mycf:c5');
```

After excecuting the script it says

```
2014-04-29 16:01:06,367 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete

2014-04-29 16:01:06,376 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-04-29 16:01:06,382 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
1.1.1   0.12.0  hduser  2014-04-29 15:58:07     2014-04-29 16:01:06     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201403142119_0084   A       MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed! Error -           JobCleanup Task Failure, Task: task_201403142119_0084_m_000001     hbase://mydata,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hbase://mydata"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201403142119_0084


2014-04-29 16:01:06,382 [main] INFO   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
```

Please help where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: What does **hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/Dataparse/file.txt** show??

Comment: file.txt is text file with comma separated values and its content is: 
15,,CO,5656,F
20,George11,MI,5555,M
1,8888a,FL,5899,F

Comment: I was not asking about for the content of the file. I just wanted the output of **hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt**..Please copy the exact output along with the command.

Comment: hadoop fs -cat /user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt

`15,,CO,5656,F

20,George11,MI,5555,M

1,8888a,FL,5899,F `

Comment: can you provide result of `list` command ran in `hbase shell`?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified too many columns in the output to hbase. You have 5 input columns and 5 output columns, but HBaseStorage requires the first column to be the row key so there should only be 4 in the output

Comment: Using pig script if i do ,A = LOAD '/user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (c1:int, c2:chararray,c3:chararray,c4:int,c5:chararray);
DUMP A;
I'm able to see the goodrec1.txt records.
Also i have -rw-r--r-- permission to the file.

Comment: I looked at it again after your comment and updated my answer with the real issue

Comment: Hi bridiver, How the hbase output columns are specified in the output as i'm new to hbase.

Comment: change

USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
          'mycf:c1,mycf:c2,mycf:c3,mycf:c4,mycf:c5')

to

USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
          'mycf:c1,mycf:c2,mycf:c3,mycf:c4')

You probably don't want to use an int as the rowkey though because you will create hotspots.

Comment: Hi If i run the below query I'm getting error as below :

Query:

`A = LOAD '/user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as c1:int,c2:chararray,c3:chararray, c4:int, c5:chararray) ;
STORE A INTO 'hbase://mydata' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage( 'mycf:c1,mycf:c2,mycf:c3,mycf:c4');`

Error :

`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!`

Comment: Have you logged into the hbase shell to make sure hbase is setup correctly and the table exists?

Comment: Yes, the table exists in hbase.

Comment: There should be additional log data for the job. The location is dependent on your configuration

Comment: I'm able to load the data from HDFS to HBASE using Pig script. Previously the problem wa with the DNS server. I changed the machine now the script is working fine.

Comment: Also one more thing i wanted to ask is suppose if i have a data with column header in HDFS , can i load this data into HBASE? Does my Hbase able to identify the Header as a filed name or it treats headers as a value ? Please clarify this

Comment: You can load files with a header by passing the correct options to the loader, but you still have to specify them in the hbase storage options

Comment: Hi,I'm able to append the daat into an existing hbase table. But the worry is whenever the new files comes into HDFS, i have to load that file into an existing hbase table.So every time i have to change the filename in the pig script and each time i ahve to run the script. Can i automate this process? It means whenever the new file comes into HDFS, my pig script has to run and load the appropriate data into a hbase table from HDFS. How can i do this?

Comment: You can use variables. If this particular problem is solved you should mark is as such and start a new one.